# How to get Leading zeros for binary numbers in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert octal numbers to binary numbers using this code

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter octal number: ");
String oct = br.readLine();
int i= Integer.parseInt(oct,8);
String binary=Integer.toBinaryString(i);
System.out.println("Octal Number: "+binary);
```

but the issue here how to get the leading zeros

Comment: what leading zeroes?

Comment: What would be the difference between octal `01` and octal `001`?

Comment: You will have to write your own formatting method

Comment: How many leading zeros do you want/need? Does the length depends on something?

Comment: like for the value `120` my result is showing `1010000` but the test case is whowing `001010000` as result

Comment: Why would you want 9 digits ??

Comment: @ajax - you want "leading zeroes for *binary* numbers", not *octal* numbers.

Comment: @Antoniossss the test cases are developed as such

Comment: Err, what is the purpose of wrapping a BufferedReader around System.in?

Comment: But again, why 9 not 8. What are padding criterias then?

Comment: You might want to use `Scanner` for `input`.  It allows you to read in numbers in a variety of formats.  And you can specify the `radix` for the input value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```java
      int[] vals = { 10, 34, 99, 1002, 40
      };
      for (int v : vals) {
         // the 07 means a field width of 7 with 0's padding on left.
         // th o means octal and the %n is newline.
         System.out.printf("%07o%n", v);
      }

      //This does the same thing but returns a formatted string.
      String paddedVal = String.format("%07o", 48);
      System.out.println(paddedVal);
```

For String already in octal.

```java
      String octalVal = "57";
      paddedVal = String.format("%07o", Integer.valueOf(octalVal, 8));
      System.out.println(paddedVal);
      // should print 0000057
```

For binary numbers.

```java
      octalVal = "57";
      String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(octalVal));
      String paddedBin =
            "00000000000000000000000000000".substring(0, 32 - bin.length())
                  + bin;
      System.out.println(paddedBin);
```

Comment: Then just convert them to octal and reformat them.  See my extended example above.

Comment: String binary not octal

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of simple task. Lets try to complement to multiply of 8;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(binaryPadLeft(Integer.toBinaryString(127)));
}

private static String binaryPadLeft(String number) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    int mod = number.length() % 8;
    if (mod > 0)
        for (int i = 0, p = 8 - mod; i < p; i++) {
            b.append('0');
        }
    b.append(number);
    return b.toString();
}
```

gives `01111111`

for `120` it yelds `01010000`